# Poles and Zeros of a Linear Transform

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, roots, invariance

Suppose I have some linear transform $T: V \rightarrow W$ where $V \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ and $W \in \mathbb{C}^{M}$ representing some Linear Time Invariant (LTI) system. Since the space is discrete, I can represent this transform as a matrix, ie:

$$ T = \begin{bmatrix}
    T_{11} & T_{12} & T_{13} & \dots  & T_{1N} \\
    T_{21} & T_{22} & T_{23} & \dots  & T_{2N} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    T_{M1} & T_{M2} & T_{M3} & \dots  & T_{MN}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now I know that the poles of this LTI system are given by the roots of $(\lambda I - T)$ In other words, the poles of the system are just the eigenvalues of $T$.

**My question: What are the zeros of the system?**

My thought is that the zeros of the system are simply the roots of $(\mathbf{v}I - T^{H})$ where $T^{H}$ means conjugate transpose. In other words, the zeros of the system are just the eigenvalues of the adjoint of $T$.

Am I correct? Is there a simple proof?